# Window Function - Range Between Dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, window-functions

I am getting error that I have a missing keyword in my code (Oracle). My idea here is to create an as/was view of spend last3,6,12. Thus, I want to know what is spend last3 for jan14, months included in the last 3 would be: Oct13,Nov13,Dec14.

merge into account_month_tb using
(   select account_month_tb.acct_id, account_month_tb.month_start_dt,

```
--rolling spend buckets
sum(spend) over
(partition by account_month_tb.acct_id order by account_month_tb.month_start_dt
range between interval '3' month preceding and preceding month) as spend_last3,

sum(spend) over
(partition by account_month_tb.acct_id order by account_month_tb.month_start_dt
range between interval '6' month preceding and preceding month) as spend_last6,

sum(spend) over
(partition by account_month_tb.acct_id order by account_month_tb.month_start_dt
range between interval '12' month preceding and preceding month) as spend_last12
--mkdn buckets


from account_month_tb

 ) rolling_14
on (account_month_tb.acct_id = rolling_14.acct_id and
account_month_tb.month_start_dt = rolling_14.month_start_dt)
when matched then update set

account_month_tb.spend_last3 = rolling_14.spend_last3,
account_month_tb.spend_last6 = rolling_14.spend_last6,
account_month_tb.spend_last12 = rolling_14.spend_last12
;
commit;
```

error message:

Error at Command Line : 163 Column : 62
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:
committed.

Comment: Maybe showing the entire statement you're executing would be helpful, along with the full error message? If this is a view you seem to be inventing new syntax.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: So is `and preceding month` supposed to be `and interval '1' month preceding`?

Answer (score 1):

Within a [windowing clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#DWHSG0201), `preceding month` doesn't mean anything and isn't valid. You appear to mean `interval '1' month preceding`.

Mocked up with some dummy data in a CTE:

```
with account_month_tb as (
  select 1 as acct_id,
    trunc(sysdate - (16 * level), 'MM') as month_start_dt,
    level as spend
  from dual
  connect by level < 10
)
select account_month_tb.acct_id, account_month_tb.month_start_dt,
  sum(spend) over (partition by account_month_tb.acct_id
    order by account_month_tb.month_start_dt
    range between interval '3' month preceding
      and interval '1' month preceding) as spend_last3
from account_month_tb;

   ACCT_ID MONTH_START_DT SPEND_LAST3
---------- -------------- -----------
         1 01-09-2014                 
         1 01-10-2014               9 
         1 01-10-2014               9 
         1 01-11-2014              24 
         1 01-12-2014              30 
         1 01-12-2014              30 
         1 01-01-2015              30 
         1 01-01-2015              30 
         1 01-02-2015              20
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40854) with the three sums and more data. You get a lot of duplication though, which probably isn't what you want. Perhaps [you just need distinct values](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40855).